# How do I color the graph in \datavisualization?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\def\mytypesetter#1{
\pgfmathparse{#1/pi}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=2}
\pgfmathroundtozerofill{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathifisint{\pgfmathresult}{
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$\pi$
}{
\pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac, frac denom=2, frac whole=false]{\pgfmathresult}$\pi$
}
}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\datavisualization [
 school book axes, %scientific axes=clean,
  all axes={},
  x axis={
    label=$\omega t$,
    ticks={
      step=(pi/2),
      tick typesetter/.code=\mytypesetter{##1},}
  },
  y axis={
    label=$v$, 
    ticks=none,
  },
  style sheet=strong colors,
  style sheet=vary dashing,
  visualize as smooth line/.list={voltage},
  voltage={label in legend={text={$v$}}},
]
data [set=voltage, format=function] {
  var x : interval [0:2*pi] samples 100;
  func y = 2*sin(\value x r);
};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

But this is what I want

[image].

How do I get this graph from my source code without using `axis` environment?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228265/121799

Comment: @marmot, I had seen but could not adapt to my source code.

Comment: I quickly tried and could at least shade the curve. Most likely one can also draw the vertical lines. However, *why* do you not want to use JouleV's nice solution or pgfplots?

Comment: It's a really nice solution. But I've got 50+ pages of graphics. If I can't find the right solution, of course I will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from adding the fills on the background.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,backgrounds}
\def\mytypesetter#1{
\pgfmathparse{#1/pi}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=2}
\pgfmathroundtozerofill{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathifisint{\pgfmathresult}{
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$\pi$
}{
\pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac, frac denom=2, frac whole=false]{\pgfmathresult}$\pi$
}
}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\datavisualization [
 school book axes, %scientific axes=clean,
  all axes={},
  x axis={
    label=$\omega t$,
    ticks={
      step=(pi/2),
      tick typesetter/.code=\mytypesetter{##1},}
  },
  y axis={
    label=$v$, 
    ticks=none,
  },
  style sheet=strong colors,
  style sheet=vary dashing,
  visualize as smooth line/.list={voltage},
  voltage={label in legend={text={$v$}}},
]
data [set=voltage, format=function] {
  var x : interval [0:2*pi] samples 100;
  func y = 2*sin(\value x r);
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \fill[red] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:pi] ({\x},{2*sin(\x r)});
 \path[pattern=horizontal lines,pattern color=red] 
 plot[variable=\x,domain=pi:2*pi] ({\x},{2*sin(\x r)});
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

This lets you keep what you had and add the fills where needed.

---

Let me also comment that [Symbol 1's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228265/121799) can be used here. I stress that I have close to zero knowledge on the data visualization business, so I may make things unnecessarily complicated. The strategy is from [Symbol 1's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228265/121799), except that I allow the style to be redefined via `\tikzset{change style={draw,pattern=horizontal lines,pattern color=red}}` (yes, I know that is a stupid name for a pgf key, yet I feel that this is not the only thing that I am doing stupid here. This works, but is far more complicated than [JouleV's nice code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481122/121799). There is a good chance that (at least) part of the complexity is due to my ignorance with regards to data visualization.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\def\mytypesetter#1{
\pgfmathparse{#1/pi}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=2}
\pgfmathroundtozerofill{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathifisint{\pgfmathresult}{
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$\pi$
}{
\pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac, frac denom=2, frac whole=false]{\pgfmathresult}$\pi$
}
}
\makeatletter%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228265/121799
\tikzdatavisualizationset{
  visualize as generic/.style={
    new object={
      when=after survey,
      store=/tikz/data visualization/visualizers/#1,
      class=plot handler visualizer,
      arg1=#1,
      arg2={\tikz@dv@plot@handler,\tikz@dv@plot@mark@maker}
    },
    new visualizer={#1}{%
      every path/.style=generic style,
      style={every mark/.append style={color=visualizer color}},
      mark size=2pt,
      semithick,
      color=visualizer color,
      mark=none,
      /tikz/data visualization/every visualize as line/.try,
    }{visualizer in legend=\tikz@dv@legend@entry@as@example},
    #1={straight line}
  },
  visualize as generic/.default=generic,
}
\tikzset{change style/.code={\tikzset{generic style/.style={#1}}},
change style={draw,fill=red}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\datavisualization [
 school book axes, %scientific axes=clean,
  all axes={},
  x axis={include value=6.3,
    label=$\omega t$,
    ticks={
      step=(pi/2),
      tick typesetter/.code=\mytypesetter{##1},}
  },
  y axis={include value=-2,
    label=$v$, 
    ticks=none,
  },
  style sheet=strong colors,
  style sheet=vary dashing,
  visualize as generic,
  %visualize as smooth line/.list={voltage},
%  voltage={label in legend={text={$v$}}},
]
data [format=function] { % set=voltage,
  var x : interval [0:pi] samples 100;
  func y = 2*sin(\value x r);
} ;
\tikzset{change style={draw,pattern=horizontal lines,pattern color=red}}
\datavisualization [
 school book axes, %scientific axes=clean,
  all axes={},
  x axis={include value=6.3,
    label=$\omega t$,
    ticks={
      step=(pi/2),
      tick typesetter/.code=\mytypesetter{##1},}
  },
  y axis={include value=2,
    label=$v$, 
    ticks=none,
  },
  style sheet=strong colors,
  style sheet=vary dashing,
  visualize as generic,
  %visualize as smooth line/.list={voltage},
%  voltage={label in legend={text={$v$}}},
]
data [format=function]{
  var x : interval [pi:2*pi] samples 100;
  func y = 2*sin(\value x r);
};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's working...

Comment: @Özgür I added a simple possibility that allows you to keep your 50+ plots and add fills where needed.

Comment: I have a small suggestion: the red color seems to overfill the *ωt* axis a bit.

Comment: @JouleV Yes, that's true, thanks! One has to use the same number of samples to get a perfect match.

Answer (score 7):

A pure Ti*k*Z solution for fun, which is much shorter. I have no idea why you have to use `\datavisualization` for this.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,y=2cm]
\draw[smooth,fill=red] plot[samples=100,domain=0:pi] (\x,{sin(deg(\x))});
\draw[smooth,pattern=horizontal lines,pattern color=red] plot[samples=100,domain=pi:2*pi] (\x,{sin(deg(\x))});
\draw[->] (0,-1.1)--(0,1.1) node[above] {$v$};
\draw[->] (-.2,0)--(2*pi+0.5,0) node[right] {$\omega t$};
\draw (pi/2,-.05) node[below] {$\frac12\pi$}--(pi/2,.05);
\draw (pi,-.05) node[below] {$1\pi$}--(pi,.05);
\draw (3*pi/2,-.05) node[below] {$\frac32\pi$}--(3*pi/2,.05);
\draw (2*pi,-.05) node[below] {$2\pi$}--(2*pi,.05);
\draw (8.5,0) node {\tikz\draw[x=1pt,y=1pt] (0,0) to[out=30,in=-150] (20,0); $v$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]